# Remove newsletter just from checkout page

Tags: checkout, newsletter

I want to remove newsletter just from checkout page and i search about it and try these codes but i don't get any result.

I add below code in `local.xml` in `app\design\frontend\default\my-theme\layout\local.xml` but nothing changed !!!

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
    <remove name="footer.newsletter"/>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Also i try this code in `checkout.xml` in `app\design\frontend\default\base\default\layout\checkout.xml` but again nothing changed !!!

```
<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
<remove name="footer.newsletter"/>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

thanks for help.

**EDIT:**

I check my code again when i add below code in `checkout.xml`, newsletter remove from all pages, why?

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
    <remove name="footer.newsletter"/>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

**EDIT2:**
This is the code of `local.xml` that show newsletter box:

```
<reference name="footer">
    <remove name="cms_footer_links"/>
    <remove name="footer_links2"/>
    <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" as="footerNewsletter"
           template="newsletter/subscribe-footer.phtml"/>                       
</reference>
```

**EDIT3:**

I search this subject again and understand that i should make my directory and copy files that i want to change them, but when i copy `checkout.xml` and change it to what i want nothing will be happen, because i should change the `Current package name`in admin panel but if i set my directory for current package name all things will mess!!! I really confused and don't know how can i solve this problem!

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you checked in your theme where the newsletter is being added? Perhaps not to the footer?

Comment: please show the code how you have call footer newletter all pages

Comment: @TimHallman : How can i check that where the newsletter is being added? I check the `newsletter.xml` and this is the block in this page:  

`<default>

        <!-- Mage_Newsletter -->
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
        </reference>

    </default>` 
Is it added in left? but i test it and nothing chenged.

Comment: please show the code  by which newsletter has been show to all pages

Comment: @amitBera : please see my edit2.

Comment: what is url of checkout page?

Comment: @AmitBera: http://example.com/checkout/cart/

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that you have it rendering in two places: left.newsletter and footerNewsLetter.

So try

```
<checkout_cart_index>
        <remove name="footerNewsletter"/>
</checkout_cart_index>

<checkout_cart_index>
        <remove name="left.newsletter"/>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

---

local.xml belongs under a theme in your package like so:

```
app\design\frontend\my-theme\default\layout\local.xml
```

You also *should* reference the parent block the newsletter was declared in.

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="footer">
        <remove name="footer.newsletter"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

**UPDATE**

Magento looks first for files in here `app/design/frontend/custom_package/custom_theme/`

then it looks for files in here `app/design/frontend/custom_package/default`

then it looks in here `app/design/frontend/base/default`

It will also look in the currently configured theme hierarchy for a local.xml

**UPDATE**

In your local.xml you are giving the block an alias footerNewsletter, you could also use that in your remove statement. Also like Amit says in his more precise answer, you should be using the cart controller in your layout update.

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="footer">
        <remove name="footerNewsletter"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

**UPDATE**

If you are unsure of how Magento's Theme Hierarchy works, I would suggest reading through the knowledge base [article on the subject](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy)

You can set your package to be live on the site by going to System -> Configuration -> Design. Then use your custom_package name

Comment: please read my question carefully,your answer is not an answer for my question!!!

Comment: I try your answer but it doesn't work !!!

Comment: Actually, you had the theme and package name's position switched around. I updated my answer with the correct path. I hope it helps..

Comment: Also FYI declaring a reference around the remove statement won't have any effect

Comment: I just have this folders in this path: `app\design\frontend\base - default - rwd`. which one of these folders do you mean?

Comment: You don't need to modify the core design files, you can create your own folder like you mentioned in your question, only it needs to be underneath the name of your template instead of above it.

Comment: You mean that where i should create folder and file to copy your code in it?

Comment: Depends really, what is the name of the package Magento is configured to use?

Comment: I don't understand, sorry.

Comment: My problem is why the code that amit said, i use the newsletter remove from all pages?!!!

Comment: I am not sure what causes it to disappear from all pages when you do what Amit suggests, as his advise is correct.